# How do you extend jQuery ColorBox to add events?

Tags: jquery, colorbox, extend

I'm new to jQuery, used Mootools for the last 5 years. I like the jQuery ColorBox modal, but I need to extend it to inlcude onCancel and onConfirm events. Can someone point out how these events can be extended to ColorBox.

Something like this:

```
$(".element").colorbox({
    onConfirm:function(){
        // some function 
    },
    onCancel:function(){ 
        // some function
    }
});
```

Comment: I think you have to add your events into the colorbox implementation, not into its call.

Comment: You can extend events and methods into something using `.extend(...)` but the problem is you still need the original code to call your events...

Comment: This was why I liked Mootools so much, class creation, extending etc. was way better. jQuery is definitely easy to use and less verbose though. If it has to be coded in the plug-in I guess I'll have to go that route.

Answer (score 1):

There are Callbacks:
http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

```
Callbacks       
onOpen  false   Callback that fires right before ColorBox begins to open.
onLoad  false   Callback that fires right before attempting to load the target    content.
onComplete  false   Callback that fires right after loaded content is displayed.
onCleanup   false   Callback that fires at the start of the close process.
onClosed    false   Callback that fires once ColorBox is closed.
```

Comment: Yes I know, but those callbacks cannot cleanly distinguish between confirms and cancels.

Comment: I suppose I can use onCleanup or onClose and pass the value of the button (true/false) on to the handler.

Comment: Yeah. But if it is not what you need. You have to check source of the jQuery plugin and add what you need. Or recommend it at the developers site :)